# Install WeChat via cocoapods issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I found WeChatSDK 0.0.1 on CocoaPods

I have added pod 'WeChatSDK', '~> 0.0.1' to my Podfile,

butI got this error after run project:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mac/Documents/Projects/Project-iOS/Pods/WeChatSDK/WeChat_SDK_iOSen'
ld: library not found for -lWeChatSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the WeChatSDK Spec [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/commit/bc53376db83886d200dde8288404aec949aed041) to use some newer hooks. This will hopefully fix your issue. Otherwise you should submit a new issue on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/new) with things like this.